# Search a specific function inside all php files in my folder

Tags: php, function, directory

I want to check in all php files in a specific folder and count how many times a specific function is being called. For example I have a function `sum()`. In my app folder I want to know which `php` file is using that function.

Comment: That magic word "xdebug"...

Comment: Yes but i want check this using another php file

Comment: @Deep maybe he wants this to be automated, without the need that he checks manually...

Comment: Sure i want create a script php wich will return for my here that function is being called

Comment: $time = microtime(true); /* your function here */ echo round(microtime(true) - $time, 3);

Comment: If you want to parse your php files, take a look at [PHP-Parser](https://github.com/nikic/PHP-Parser). You may want to read the documentation about Walking the AST and Node Finder.